# I need someone to explain this shape to me.

Tags: geometry

[image: The shape]

The hexagon fits in the circle perfectly, the circle fits in the square perfectly.
but the hexagon doesn't fit in the square perfectly. Doesn't this defy this formula below?
a = b
b = c
a = c (what happens in that shape is a =/= b)

Excuse my ignorance as I'm not a math student myself. I just need a clear explanation.

Comment: "fits perfectly" is not "transitive" as we say. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation   In particular "fits perfectly" is not "equal".

Comment: You might want to find a mathematical (or otherwise precise) way to say "fits inside perfectly." For sure the square is not equal to the circle. And in your picture, the hexagon is touching the square in two places.

Comment: What you are describing is a *relation* that is not *transitive*. Googling the mathematical definition of those two terms might be helpful to you.

Comment: Draw a triangle inside of a square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your confusion probably comes from the fact that you write $a = b$ to mean “$a$ fits perfectly into $b$” instead of the usual “$a$ is equal to $b$”.

The ‘$=$’ symbol carries some assumptions, and one of them is that it is a [*transitive* relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation). This is exactly what you were describing: a relation ‘$\sim$’ (using a more generic symbol to avoid confusion) is called *transitive* if and only if $a\sim b$ and $b\sim c$ together imply $a\sim c$ (for all $a,b,c$ in the domain of interest). Equality is a transitive relation, and several other relations are transitive as well, e.g. the ordering relation ‘$<$’. Or in this case more relevant, the congruence between shapes would be a transitive relation as well. (It would even be an [equivalence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation), which is a stronger requirement and one often associated with a symbol like ‘$=$’.)

But your “fits perfectly into” relation is *not* transitive. As you observed yourself. And there is no mathematical reason it should be. The main reason why you assumed that it *might* be is in my opinion because you used a symbol for this relation which usually describes a transitive relation.